# Symfony 2 PDFBundle > Class 'ZendPdf\PdfDocument' not found

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've installed the PDFBundle https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle following the instructions described there.

It is running fine in my local server (dev enviroment) but, in my production enviroment I can't get it running.

I've uploaded all this files and folders to my server:

```
/app/config.yml
/app/AppKernel.php
/app/autoload.php
/vendor/composer (complete folder)
/vendor/psliwa (complete folder)
/vendor/autoload.php
/composer.lock
/composer.json
```

What can I be missing to upload to my server? Is there anything else that I could be missing to upload?

Another question, I am having all this issues (i believe) because I can't access to my server to execute a composer install (I am on a shared hosting). Is there anyway to run composer install on shared hostings?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't run Composer on shared hosting most of the time because you have no access to a command line, and even if you'd fake this, you probably don't have version control systems installed.

The usual way even with servers that do offer a command line is to run `composer install` prior to uploading everything to the server on a system that you have a working command line on, and can influence the PHP installation. However make sure you are using the same PHP version on this system that is used in production! Some packages do have dependencies on certain PHP versions, and using a too old PHP in production will trigger all kinds of issues when using software that expects to not have to deal with the bugs in older PHP versions.

Regarding your original problem: I cannot really see what is wrong, but I do see that there are no tagged version of this project released, so you are forced to install from a branch - which is a nasty thing because you cannot really pinpoint a problem to a known working version like when using a tag.

And by the way: The installation instructions are bad. Never use "minimum-stability:dev" if you can avoid it or can deal with the consequences. It allows Composer to install development versions of EVERYTHING you include, and these are very likely broken.

My best recommendation would be to abandon that project and try to find a better one with tagged versions for PDF creation. If you cannot do this, create a ticket with the project on github and recommend they tag a commit as a released version.

And maybe you triggered a bug with the last occurence of a Zend Framework 1 PDF class with your code. I can see the project has an older branch with a name that suggests they used to use ZF1 as a backend.